# fortran gives wrong number in function

Tags: function, fortran

I have this simple program in fortran

```
program T55
   integer i,j
   double precision x(1,100),D,ff,g

   do i=1,5
      x(1,i)=5
   enddo
   D=1
   do i=6,8
      x(1,i)=11
     write(*,*)x(1,i)
   enddo
   do i=1,4
      g=ff(i,x(1,i),D)
   enddo
end program T55
double precision function ff(i,x,D)
   integer i,j
   double precision x(1,100),D
   D=1
   write(*,*)x(1,i),i

end function ff
```

The number I get from Function is incorrect for example I get

```
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 11
```

Could you please tell me where I made mistake?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  To me, the leading 1 and trailing 11 are a bit unexpected, but I also expect this to start by outputting 11 three times.

Answer (score 2):

Let me execute your program for you:

after the first loop (do i =1,5)

```
index =  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...
x     =(/5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .../)
```

where ? represents undefined values

after the second loop (do i =6,8)

```
index =   1  2  3  4  5   6   7  ...
x     = (/5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 11, 11, 11, ?, ?.../)
```

in the loop (i=1,4) this is what happened:

i = 1: you call ff with i=1 and the whole array x, (I ignore the argument D it 
is unused)

ff print the element at position 1 of its array argument, that is 5

i = 2, you call ff with i=2 and an array starting at index 2 of x.

ff print the element at position 2 of its array argument, that  corresponds to the index 3 of the original array and it contains 5

i = 3, you call ff with i=3 and an array starting at index 3 of x.

ff print the element at position 3 of its array argument, that  corresponds to the index 5 of the original array and it contains 5

i = 4, you call ff with i=4 and an array starting at index 4 of x.

ff print the element at position 4 of its array argument, that  corresponds to the index 7 of the original array and it contains 11